# How to get child items from a DropTree (itemlink) path in JSS using React

Tags: jss

Is there a way to get child items from a droptree (itemlink) path in JSS using React without using GraphQL?

I see there are `LayoutService` but it only retrieves child from the `contextItem` or `DataSource`. I want to retrieve child item from the `DropTree` field on the template.

For example, I have Footer template where I have field `Social Media Links Folder path` which is `DropTree` field. So in JSS React code, I want to retrieve like

```
const Footer = (props) => {

  const model = props.fields ? props.fields : {}

  const child = model.socialLinks.children
}
```

Comment: Create your own content resolver  https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/extending-layout-service/layoutservice-rendering-contents

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any example where it reads data from other template field to get path and from that path get all child items? I am not sure creating custom one will resolve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom resolver by inheriting RenderingContentsResolver
Over ride ResolveContents method, get your data source item, which will have the droptree field. you can get the child/related items details and create your JObject item to return, as per your requirement.